# Can I resolder a power connections with a partially burnt board

Tags: ramps-1.6

Recently my RAMPS power connector caught fire while heating the heated bed. I suspect this was a defect caused by the connector, and de-soldered/removed it as best I could. I'm  not an electrical engineer, so I'm looking for advice on whether It is possible to re-solder the power connectors directly onto the board, or I'm just risking another fire. Here are pictures of the top and bottom.

[image: Top side of PCB and underside of power screw terminals, showing burning]

[image: Underside of PCB]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MIck wrote, we hope your board isn't damaged - with any luck there aren't any trace shorts in the melted region.

My approach would be slightly different.  Use some short bits of wire soldered into the board at one end and soldered to a new connector socket at the other end.  This way you can put a new plug connector on the power leads and be able to disconnect the board as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Possible? Yes. Advisable? Perhaps not. Since it is the power connection, I would be tempted to solder the cables directly to the board. If the board is found to work, I would then install an external MOSFET for the heated bed, to reduce the amount of current that the controller has to handle.